# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinContext when using Zeppelin input value inside spark DataFrame's filter method

Tags: apache-spark, classnotfoundexception, apache-zeppelin

I'm having a trouble for two days already, and can't find any solutions.

I'm getting

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinContext
```

when using input value inside spark DataFrame's filter method.

```
val city = z.select("City",cities).toString
oDF.select("city").filter(r => city.equals(r.getAs[String]("city"))).count()
```

I even tried copying the input value to another val with

```
new String(bytes[])
```

but still get the same error.

The same code work seamlessly if instead of getting the value from z.select
I declare as a String literal

`city: String = "NY"
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0
in stage 49.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage
49.0 (TID 277, 10.6.60.217): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
Lorg/apache/zeppelin/spark/ZeppelinContext;`

Comment: The first line has been executed successfully since city already assigned value "NY". And the class `org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinContext` shall be certainly packed in Zeppelin. I guess you running with an external Spark, which possibly user z in certain way. Try to split code in different paragraph and run it.

Comment: Yes I am running with an external Spark. Same error after splitting into two paragraphs

Answer (score 0):

You are taking this in the wrong direction:

```
val city="NY"
```

gives you a scala String with NY as the string, but when you say

```
z.select("City",cities)
```

then this returns you dataFrame and then you are converting this object to String using method toString and then trying to compare.!

This wont work !

What you can do is either collect one dF and then pass the scala String accordingly into the other Df or you can do a join if you want to do it for multiple values.

But this approach will not work for sure !

Comment: the z variable it is not a dataFrame. Is the Zeppelin Context default variable, therefore the select method, is not the select method from Spark's DataFrame. This select method returns an Object which is converted to String with toString.

Comment: Cn you get the value after applying the toString , can you print it ?

Comment: yes sure I can print it. The problem is when the variable is used inside DataFrame's filter method. It seams like it is lately evaluated outside the Spark's driver, and on a remote node where there is no org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinContext. Zeppelin uses a local driver and submits and Application to the Spark cluster